# Angularjs ui-router event

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a page that uses angular ui-router to render two views on the same page.
I ultimately need to have this run under phonegap/cordova so will have to bootstrap angular to the elements on a deviceready event.

I managed to encapsulate the code into a function and when the function is called at the end of the page it works fine.

However when the same function is called on the window.onload or document ready event it fails to work. In fact if the function is called from the javascript console itself after page load it just fails to work.

Need help figuring out what is exactly going wrong.

Code below

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script>

</script>   
</head>
<body>
<div ui-view="appview"> appview     </div>
<div ui-view="msgview"> messageview s</div>
<script>

var  routerApp;
var appViews = ['appview','msgview'];   


function zero()
{
    routerApp= angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);
    x=$("body").attr("ng-app","routerApp");     
    for(var i=0;i<appViews.length;i++)
    {
        angular.bootstrap($("#" + appViews[i]), ["routerApp"]); 
    }

    routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) 
    {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/messaging');
        $stateProvider
        .state('messaging', 
        {
            url: '/messaging',
            views:
            {
                '':{templateUrl:'http://geo.tikoo.com/app/components/messaging/phone/messaging.html'},
                'msgview':
                {
                    templateUrl: 'http://geo.tikoo.com/app/components/messaging/phone/messaging.html',
                    controller: 'messC'
                }
            }

        });

    });
routerApp.controller('messC', function($scope) {

        $scope.username = 'Tom';
    });
}
zero();
//window.onload=zero;
//$(document).ready(function(){zero();}); 



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after a few attempts.

Here is what needed to be done.
1. The routers need to be set first.
2. The attribute for ng-app on the element needs to be set next.
3. a angular.element(element).ready event needs to be caught to bootstrap

**Understanding.**
If the routers are not setup first then the bootstrapping fails (obvious)
The ng-app dynamic addition also needs the router setup (Interestingly chrome can work in any order but mobile browser/opera needs that router be setup first before the attribute ng-app is assigned to an element).

**SET ROUTERS ==> ADD ng-app Attribute to element ==> Bootstrap**

Hope this helps